# Site_url não funciona no CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Estou seguindo um tutorial do CodeIgniter ess trecho de código não está funcionando na minha máquina, já configurei tudo direitinho, até os outros tutoriais já funcionaram, porém esse trecho de código não está funcionando:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url()?>sobre">Sobre</a>
```

No tutorial funcionou bacana, mas aqui não.

Comment: Por acaso esta carregando o helper url? `$this->load->helper('url')`. E costumo colocar o link dentro dos parenteses, mesmo funcionando fora, acho que fica melhor visualmente! `<a href="<?php echo site_url('sobre')?>">Sobre</a>`

Comment: Como eu carrego o Helper URL? Marcelo.

Comment: Dentro da própria View ou no Controller?

Comment: Ou vc pode carregar no seu arquivo application/autoload.php ou no controller. Se for no autoload . `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'html');` , se for no controller `$this->load->helper('url');`

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh... Agora funcionou mano, é que no tutorial o cara não explica que tem que carregar o helper, valeu mesmo... Cria lá a resposta que eu vou marcar como Resposta certa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve carregar o helper url, ou no autoload ou no controller:

Se for no autoload  `application/autoload.php` procure por `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

Se for no controller `$this->load->helper('url');`

Comment: Obrigado Marcelo Diniz